# what is the default allocation when resources are not specified in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, kubernetes-pod

Below is kubernetes POD definition

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: static-web
  labels:
    role: myrole
spec:
  containers:
    - name: web
      image: nginx
      ports:
        - name: web
          containerPort: 80
          protocol: TCP
```

as I have not specified the resources, how much Memory & CPU will be allocated? Is there a kubectl to find what is allocated for the POD?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If resources are not specified for the Pod, the Pod will be scheduled to any node and resources are not considered when choosing a node.

The Pod might be "terminated" if it uses more memory than available or get little CPU time as Pods with specified resources will be prioritized. It is a good practice to set resources for your Pods.

See [Configure Quality of Service for Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/quality-service-pod/) - your Pod will be classified as "Best Effort":

> For a Pod to be given a QoS class of BestEffort, the Containers in the Pod must not have any memory or CPU limits or requests.

Comment: Kubectl get po xx - o yaml shows me 100M & 2Gi, does it mean that allocated resources are 100M & 2Gi?

Comment: That means that you have set resources for the Pod, or that something has set some default resources. For actual allocation you need to look at metrics or `kubectl top pod <podname>`. It depends if these are "requests" or "limits" as well.

Answer (score 3):

In your case, `kubernetes` will assign `QoS` called `BestEffort` to your pod.
That's means `kube-scheduler` has no idea how to schedule your pod and just do its best.

That's also means your pod can consume any amount of resource（cpu/mem）it want (but the `kubelet` will evict it if anything goes wrong).

To see the resource cost of your pod, you can use `kubectl top pod xxxx`